# JavaScript Canvas Issue in FireFox, works fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to the stack over flow; but have found many of the topics discussed here quite helpful in the development of web applications.

However, this time I am stumped. I wrote a few simple functions in JavaScript to add an undo/redo feature when using the new HTML5 canvas. The code I wrote runs fine in Chrome, but in Firefox does not function; I think I have isolated the issue to the line of code where I am placing an image object into an array (works fine in Chrome). I have researched this and I could not find any reason why this would not work in FireFox. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function push()
{
window.cStep++;
    if (window.cStep < window.history.length) { window.history.length = window.cStep; }
var imageData = window.context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
alert(imageData);
window.history[window.cStep] = imageData;
     document.title = "Step [" +window.cStep + "] Of A Possible [" +    (window.history.length -1) + "]";
 }

 function undo()
 {
  if (window.cStep > 0) {
    window.cStep--;
    window.context.putImageData(window.history[window.cStep], 0, 0);
    document.title = "Step [" +window.cStep + "] Of A Possible [" + (window.history.length -1) + "]";
    if(window.cStep ==0)
    {document.getElementById('middle_centre_canvas').style.opacity = 0.6;}
    else
    {document.getElementById('middle_centre_canvas').style.opacity = 1;}
     }  
   }
    function redo()
   {
    if (window.cStep < window.history.length-1) {
    window.cStep++;
    window.context.putImageData(window.history[window.cStep],0,0);
    document.title = "Step [" +window.cStep + "] Of A Possible [" + (window.history.length -1) + "]";
    if(window.cStep >0)
    {document.getElementById('middle_centre_canvas').style.opacity = 1;}
    }
   }
      function loadyLoader(){
    window.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    window.context = window.canvas.getContext('2d');
    window.history = new Array();
    window.cStep = -1;
    push();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.history is a reserved object : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp.
Try to replace all **window.history** occurrences with **window._history** (or another name).

Comment: Can't believe it - exactly that, works great now thanks! This one had me stumped for hours as well lol.